# Yii1 - How to bypass an access rule

Tags: yii, permissions, frameworks, roles, yii1.x

I'm working on a project in Yii, and I have almost no experience with this framework and php.

I'm trying to give access to a view in Yii to different users depending on their role. In my code, in the Controller/accessRules function, I give permission to users with a specific role, that's working fine.

The thing/problem is: I also need to give that same permission to a specific users from very different roles and those roles they don't have to have permission. But those specific users they have a field activated in the 'users' table in the database (it's a boolean field, 1/0 values). If that field has a '1', those users must access to the view, if it's a '0', they don't.

I tried to check the value of the field I described before but the thing is if they don't have the role described in the accessRules, they don't have access. (or maybe the way I check this is not well done).

What I need to do to solve this? I need some tips. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found a solution. Not the one I was expecting but effective... I created a new role/profile in the database and added the role to the users I want to give access, also in the database. Then in the app I added the new role in the controller/action of the view, that's all. It's simple, I know. But I think it's not the best idea because of if the number of users starts growing and in the case every user needs a specific role...maybe it's too much work.